# How to perform an api call when closing a React app?

Tags: reactjs, session-storage

I have a React app that stores each profile page viewed in session storage. Once the user closes the app, I need to send this array to the server, so it can perform a bulk write on the database.

I have thus added this function in the clean-up part of the useEffect on top of the app. But typescript claims that:

> Argument of type '() => () => Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'.
> Type '() => Promise' is not assignable to type 'void | Destructor'.

Here is the code:

```js
// app.tsx
export default function App() {
  const {saveProfileVisits} = userService()
  useEffect(() => {
    initializeUser()
    return ()=> saveProfileVisits()
  }, [saveProfileVisits]);
  
  
// saveProfileVisits
export interface UserService {
   saveProfileVisits: () => Promise<any>; 
 }
 
 const saveProfileVisits: UserService["saveProfileVisits"] = async () => {
  try {
    const visitedProfiles = await getSessionStorageVisitedProfiles();
    return api.post("/save-visited-profiles", visitedProfiles);
  } catch (err) {
    return null;
  }
};
```

How to fix this? Also, is this the best way to perform an api call when the user quits the app? If there is a better solution, I'd be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a promise from your saveProfileVisits function.
Try just making your post request without returning the result (the promise).

Answer (score 0):

return **await** api.post("/save-visited-profiles", visitedProfiles);